# How to resume .partial download in Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, download

I am having a small *yet annoying* issue.

## Firstly...

...I went to the apple.developer website to download XCode 7.1 (I didn't download it from the Mac App store because it would take longer). I got to around 51% when I decided to **turn of my PC**. I made sure I **paused it** before I shut it down.

## Now...

...I turned on my PC and went back to Internet Explorer. Unfortunately when I went back to the Downloads window the **download was not there**. (*With anger*) I went to my downloads folder to check if I could find maybe a .partialdownload or .partial file.

---

## Question:

There is a file named...

> Xcode_7.1.dmg.kvkyj65.partital

...in the downloads folder. It has a size of **1,533,715 kb (1.5GB)**. I am guessing this maybye where my file is being downloaded and has stopped. My question is **is there a way to resume the download with this file?**

---

*Operating System: Windows 10*

*Browser: Internet Explorer 11*

Comment: What happens if you just double-click the `partial` file?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 When I *double-clicked* it, it took me to a blank page on Internet Explorer which the redirected to a downloads window and then nothing happened.

Comment: years ago I recall some people using download managers, maybe they still exist

Comment: @barlop Any suggestions of download managers?...

Comment: @RACING121 this site normally has really good freeware programs , here is their download manager section http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/internet/dlman.html